# Remove last character from textbox on button click

Tags: vb.net, textbox, backspace

I have a `textbox`, `textbox1`, whose `ReadOnly` property is set to true. It is somewhat like an on-screen keyboard. When the user presses a button, I can add characters by using:

```
Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text & A
```

But, when the user wants to remove the text, which should work exactly like the  <kbd>Backspace</kbd>  key, the last character should be removed from the `textbox`.

I am ready to give up normal `textbox` and use `richtextbox` if there is any way ahead with the rich one.

How to **remove last character of a textbox with a button?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previously suggested `SubString` method is what I would have posted too.  However, there is an alternative.  The `Remove` method works by removing every character after the given index.  For instance:

```
TextBox1.Text = Textbox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Nice!  How have I overlooked this method all these years?  Good to know.  Thanks.  +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SubString` method to get all but the last character, for instance:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.SubString(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above functions such as `Substring` and `Remove` are not executed in Visual Basic 6 (or earlier versions). I recommend to use `Mid` function.

For instance,in this example last character of `Hello` is deleted and rest of word is saved in `Text1`

```
Text1=Mid("Hello",1, Len("Hello") - 1)
```

and result is `Text1=Hell`